# how to send extra_context to submit_line.html in django?

Tags: python, django

Using change_view I can send context to `change_form.html` without any problem, but when I try to use `{{ show_save_as_draft }}` in `submit_line.html`, it does not show anything.

Here is my change_view function:

```
def change_view(self, request,object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context["show_save_as_draft"] = True
    return super(ArticleAdmin, self).change_view(request,object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

Comment: It looks like that approach isn't going to work, because the [`submit_row`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a0047c6242fd48068eb444e0a58f7a5d2bc1bcd3/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_modify.py#L24) template tag that renders the `submit_line.html` template constructs a new context `ctx` instead of using the provided context that contains your 'show_save_as_draft'.

Comment: Could you derive the necessity to show the *Save as draft* button based on information on the object that is currently edited? Because this is available as `{{ original }}` in `submit_line.html`. So if you have anything there to analyze it or maybe write a method like `should_show_save_as_draft_button()` that returns a flag this might be a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own templatetag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('admin/submit_line.html', takes_context=True)
def submit_line_row(context):
    context = context or {}
    ctx= admin_modify.submit_row(context)
    if "show_save_as_draft" in context.keys():
        ctx["show_save_as_draft"] = context["show_save_as_draft"]
    return  ctx
```

More at my blog: http://www.sadafnoor.com/blog/one-workaroud-to-pass-variables-context-to-django-admin-submit_line-html-template/